# How to run half precision inference on a TensorRT model, written with TensorRT C++ API?

Tags: c++, deep-learning, precision, inference-engine, tensorrt

I'm trying to run half precision inference with a model natively written in TensorRT C++ API (not parsed from other frameworks e.g. caffe, tensorflow);
To the best of my knowledge, there is no public working example of this problem; the closest thing I found is the sampleMLP sample code, released with [TensorRT 4.0.0.3](https://developer.nvidia.com/tensorrt), yet the [release notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-release-notes/rel_4.html) say there is no support for fp16;

My toy example code can be found in [this repo](https://github.com/FrancescoB-Vintra/fp16tensorRT). It contains API-implemented architecture and inference routine, plus the python script I use to convert my dictionary of trained weights to the wtd TensorRT format.

My toy architecture only consists of one convolution; the goal is to obtain similar results between fp32 and fp16, except for some reasonable loss of precision; the code seems to work with fp32, whereas what I obtain in case of fp16 inferencing are values of totally different orders of magnitude (~1e40); so it looks like I'm doing something wrong during conversions;

I'd appreciate any help in understanding the problem.

Thanks,

f

Answer (score 1):

After quickly reading through your code, I can see you did more than is necessary to get a half precision optimized network. You shouldn't manually convert the loaded weights from `float32` to `float16` yourself. Instead, you should create your network as you normally would and call `nvinfer1::IBuilder::setFp16Mode(true)` with your `nvinfer1::IBuilder` object to let TensorRT do the conversions for you where suitable.